# I Can't define string in dart with $ in it

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use this as String in Dart.

```dart
String s = 'reservoir$lbc_release'
```

Getting error due to `$`. How do I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just use escape sequence

```
print('Hello \$');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use '\' in front of '$'

```
String s = 'reservoir\$lbc_release'
```